# Using Golang to Post data to NFT.Storage

Tags: go

I'm trying to send form data to [NFT Storage](https://nft.storage/). When I use the following cURL it works:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://api.nft.storage/store' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer MYPRETTYTOKEN' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'meta={"name": "Hello","image": null}'
```

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
func (h *Handler) uploadNftImage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    data := Payload{"Hello", nil}
    payloadBytes, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    mystring := string(payloadBytes)

    params := url.Values{}
    params.Add("meta", mystring)
    body := strings.NewReader(params.Encode())
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.nft.storage/store", body)

    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    req.Header.Set("accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "MYPRETTYTOKEN")

    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
}
```

When using this I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error. When I dump the request in Postman I get the following:

```
POST /store HTTP/1.1
Host: api.nft.storage
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 56
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer MTPRETTYTOKEN
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Accept-Encoding: gzip

meta=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Hello%22%2C%22image%22%3Anull%7D
```

I've also not encoded the data and got the following:

```
POST /store HTTP/1.1
Host: api.nft.storage
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 56
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer MTPRETTYTOKEN
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Accept-Encoding: gzip

meta={"name":"Hello","image":null}
```

I honestly can't see where I'm going wrong or there is a bug on their side. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think providing an image resource as "null" would be digest to the server

Comment: Also the request is multipart/form-data but does not contain any multipart section. You might need to add the payload of the image added to the "meta" JSON content.